Input opreand Error during Python programming
I'm programming the code below in Python to simulate a control system. However, when I debug the code, I'm facing the following issue:
matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
File "D:\Área de Trabalho\GitHub\TCC\Códigos Marcela\SistemaSISO_tres_estados_new.py", line 110, in 
un[i]= alpha + beta@vn[i]
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
Could you please help me to solve it??
import numpy as np

from numpy import cos,sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import control.matlab as mat
from scipy.linalg import solve_continuous_are as arec

plt.close('all')

#Vetor Tempo ---------------------------------------------------
inter =20#tempo de simulação 
T = 0.05#frequencia de simulação 
t = np.arange(0,4*inter,T)

#Ganho estático ------------------------------------------------
A=np.array([[0,1,0],
            [0,0,1],
            [0,0,0],
            ])
B=np.array([[0],
            [0],
            [1],
            ])
# K= mat.place(A,B,[-10,-9,-28])
ep=3

K= mat.place(A,B,[-1.0253*ep,-0.3830*ep,-1.1998*ep])
print(K)

#Constantes do modelo -------------------------------------------
Mg = 0.88
I1 = 6.8e-2
I2 = 2e-2
B1_psi = 6e-3
B1_phi = 1e-1
Kgy = 0.05
K1 = 1.1
K2 = 0.8
T11 = 1.1
T10 = 1
T21 = 1
T20 = 1
Kc = -0.2
a1 = 0.0135
b1 = 0.0924
a2 = 0.02
b2 = 0.09

#Setpoint ------------------------------------------------------
SetPoint = np.ones((3,len(t))) #pré alocando o vetor de setpoint

h0 = [0.1, 0.32, -0.15, -0.15 ]
h1 = [0.05, 0.1, 0.02, -0.1]
c1 = 3
SetPoint[0,:] = SetPoint[0,:]*h0[0]
SetPoint[1,:] = SetPoint[1,:]*0

for k in range(len(t)):
    for i in range(1,len(h0)):
        SetPoint[0,k] += (h0[i] - h0[i-1] )/( 1 + np.exp(-c1*(t[k] - inter*i - 0.1 )) )

SetPoint[2,:] =  (-b1 + np.sqrt(b1**2 + 4*a1*Mg*np.sin(SetPoint[0,:])))/(2*a1)

# Pré alocação dos vetores do sistema =============================
# Sistema Nominal ------------------------------------------------
xn = np.zeros((3,len(t))) #pré alocando o vetor de estados 
un = np.zeros(len(t)) #pré  alocando o vetor de sinal de controle não linear 
vn = np.zeros(len(t)) #pré alocando o vetor de sinal linear
en= np.zeros((3,1)) #pré alocando o vetor de erro

# Condições Iniciais----------------------------------------------
xn[0,0]=0.1
xn[1,0]=0
xn[2,0]=0

# # Outras definições
# iF = 1.4 # iF = 0.9 deixa o sistema incerto instável quando não tem saturação no sinal de controle
# iG1 = 1
# iG2 = 1

while i<(len(t)-1):

    x1 = xn[0,i]
    x2 = xn[1,i]
    x3 = xn[2,i]

    en[0,0] = x1 - SetPoint[0,i]
    en[1,0] = x2 - SetPoint[1,i] 
    en[2,0] = -B1_psi*x2/I1 - Mg*sin(x1)/I1 + a1*x3**2/I1 + b1*x3/I1 -(-B1_psi*SetPoint[1,i]/I1 - Mg*sin(SetPoint[0,i])/I1 + a1*SetPoint[2,i]**2/I1 + b1*SetPoint[2,i]/I1)

    vn[i] = np.reshape(-K@en, (1))
            
    A = np.array([[K1*(2*a1*x3/I1 + b1/I1)/T11, 0], [-1.75*K1*Kc*(2*a1*x3 + b1)/(I2*T11), K2*(b2/I2)/T21]])

    Lf = np.array([[-B1_psi*(-B1_psi*x2/I1 - Mg*sin(x1)/I1 + a1*x3**2/I1 + b1*x3/I1)/I1 - T10*(2*a1*x3/I1 + b1/I1)*x3/T11 + (-Kgy*(a1*x3**2 + b1*x3)*cos(x1)/I1)*(- 1.75*Kc*(a1*x3**2 + b1*x3)/I2) + (-Mg*cos(x1)/I1)*x2], [-B1_phi*(- 1.75*Kc*(a1*x3**2 + b1*x3)/I2)/I2 - 1.75*Kc*T10*(2*a1*x3 + b1)*x3/(I2*T11)]])
    
    F1 = x2
    F2 = a1/I1*x3**2 + b1/I1*x3 -Mg/I1*sin(x1) - B1_psi/I1*x2
    F3 = -T10/T11*x3

    F = np.array([F1, F2, F3])

    G1 = np.array([10e-7,10e-7,K1/T11])

    # try: 
    # beta = 1/G1
    # alpha = -F/G1
    beta = np.linalg.inv(A)
    alpha = -beta@Lf
    un[i]= alpha + beta@vn[i]         
    # except:
    #     print('Matriz singular')
    #     un[i] = 1

    xn[:, i + 1] = xn[:, i] + T * (F + G1 * un[i])
    
    i=i+1
un[-1]=un[-2]


plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(t,xn[0,:],'b')
plt.plot(t,SetPoint[0,:],'--k')
plt.xlim((0,80))
plt.ylim((-0.2,0.55))
plt.ylabel('$x_1$ $[rad]$')
#plt.xlabel('t [s]')
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(312)
plt.plot(t,xn[1,:],'b')
plt.plot(t,SetPoint[1,:],'--k')
plt.xlim((0,80))
#plt.ylim((0,70))
plt.ylabel('$x_2$ $[rad/s]$')
#plt.xlabel('t [s]')
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(313)
plt.plot(t,xn[2,:],'b')
plt.plot(t,SetPoint[2,:],'--k')
plt.xlim((0,80))
#plt.ylim((0,70))
plt.ylabel('$x_5$ $[Nm]$')
#plt.xlabel('t [s]')
plt.grid()

plt.show()


I tried to use a reshape to change the vector dimensions but it's not working...
